# getting my image map to work between the HTML and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

The issue I am having is getting the image map to work from the Home.html
I have an interactive menu that displays a second bar after clicking an item in the first bar and an image after clicking in the second bar. I want to use an image map to display little information popups when certain areas of different images are hovered over. I can get the hover function to work when the image map is in an isolated html file. but when I want to implement it from Home.html i'm not exactly sure how to make it work. not sure what I am missing. help is appreciated.

The Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#bar2").hide();

$(document).on("click", ".subItem", function () { //we use $.on instead of $.bind here because the .subItem class elements we are binding 'click' events to do not exist yet in the DOM, and won't for an indeterminate amount of time since they require user action to appear.
    var tid = $(this).attr("id");
    var type = tid.split("-");
    var subNum = type[1];
    var makeGet = type[0];
    var make = window[makeGet];

    $("#daPic").empty().append("<img src='" + make.models[subNum].image + "' />");
});
function updateBar2(makeObject, IDprefix) {
    $("#bar2").show().empty();
    var cutitoff = "";
    var container = 0;
    for (item in makeObject.models) {
        cutitoff += "<div class='subItem' id='" + IDprefix + "-" + item + "'>" + makeObject.models[item].name + "</div> | ";
        container += 102; //Adjust this if your menu item text grows significantly
    }
    cutitoff = cutitoff.substr(0, cutitoff.length - 2);
    $("#bar2").append(cutitoff).css("width", container + "px");
}
$("#item1").bind("click", function () {
    updateBar2(Honda1, "Honda1");
});
$("#item2").bind("click", function () {
    updateBar2(Honda2, "Honda2");
});
$("#item3").bind("click", function () {
    updateBar2(Honda3, "Honda3");
});
$("#item4").bind("click", function () {
    updateBar2(Honda4, "Honda4");
});

/*AREA MAP STUFF*/
$("area").hover(function () {
    var info = $(this).attr("href");
    //$(".areaPop").hide();
    $(info).show();
}, function () {
    $(".areaPop").hide();
});

area.bind("areaPop", function (e) {
    area.children(".areaPop").show().offset({ left: e.pageX + 10, top: e.pageY + 10 });
    e.preventDefault();
});

});

//would be better to create a parent Products object to enclose all Hondas, etc. so you don't have to link individual objects to their controls above.
var Honda1 = new Object();

Honda1.models = new Array();

Honda1.models = [{ name: "HRX217VKA", image: "images/hrx/hrx217vka.png" }, { name: "HRX217VLA", image: "images/hrx/hrx217vla.png" }, { name: "HRX217VYA", image: "images/hrx/hrx217vya.png" }, { name: "HRX217HYA", image: "images/hrx/hrx217hya.png" }, { name: "HRX217HZA", image: "images/hrx/hrx217hza.png" }];
/*The Honda1 object has a property called models, which is an array (we access inside the []) that contains nested objects (accessed inside the {}s) with properties pertaining to their respective names and image paths. The notation for this is {propertyname : propertyvalue, propertyname : propertyvalue, ad infinitum...}*/

var Honda2 = {}; //correct notation for new object

Honda2.models = []; //correct notation for new array

Honda2.models = [{ name: "HRR216PKA", image: "images/hrr/hrr216pka.png" }, { name: "HRR216VKA", image: "images/hrr/hrr216vka.png" }, { name: "HRR216VYA", image: "images/hrr/hrr216vya.png" }, { name: "HRR216VLA", image: "images/hrr/hrr216vla.png" }];

var Honda3 = {};

Honda3.models = [];

Honda3.models = [{ name: "HRS216PKA", image: "images/hrs/hrs216pka.png" }, { name: "HRS216SKA", image: "images/hrs/hrs216ska.png" }]

var Honda4 = {};

Honda4.models = [];

Honda4.models = [{ name: "HRC216PDA", image: "images/hrc/hrc216pda.png" }, { name: "HRC216HXA", image: "images/hrc/hrc216hxa.png" }]
```

The home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js" language="javascript"></script>
<title>stuff</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="bar1" class="center">
        <div id="item1" class="mainBarItem">HONDA HRX</div> ||
        <div id="item2" class="mainBarItem">HONDA HRR</div> || 
        <div id="item3" class="mainBarItem">HONDA HRS</div> ||
        <div id="item4" class="mainBarItem">HONDA HRC</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bar2" class="center"></div> 
    <div id="daPic" class="center" style="width:600px;"></div>
    <!-- image map divs --> 
    <div id="gxv160" class="areaPop">
        The GXV160 Honda motor provides superior power with reliable and easy starting. The GXV160 also comes with an industry leading 2 year residential and commercial warranty. 
    </div>
    <div id="microcut" class="areaPop">
        Honda's exclusive MicroCut® utilizes four cutting surfaces to provide superior mulching and bagging. Fit 30% more clippings in a bag or provide your lawn with a better mulch.
    </div>
    <div id="precisionspeedcontrol" class="areaPop">
        The durable commercial grad hydrostatic trasmission in this mower provides variable speed control from 2.1 to 4 mph. Keep up with ground conditions as they change.
    </div>
    <div id="rotostop" class="areaPop">
        Honda Roto-Stop® blade stop system lets you step away from the mower without having to stop and restart the engine. The self propulsion continues to function also allowing for effortless transportation between work areas.
    </div>
    <div id="2.5bushelbag" class="areaPop">
        A large 2.5 bushel easy empty grass catcher holds more so you can stop less.
    </div>
    <div id="shaftdrive" class="areaPop">
        An automotive style drive shaft powers this mower eliminating the need to service belts and pulleys.
    </div>
    <div id="9inchnexitewheel" class="areaPop">
        Stong, lightweight and easy to replace when needed.
    </div>
    <div id="9inchballbearing" class="areaPop">
        9" wheels with ball bearings offer better maneuverability, smoother drive, and increased durability.
    </div>
    <div id="8inchballbearing" class="areaPop">
        8" wheels with ball bearings offer better maneuverability, smoother drive, and increased durability.
    </div>
    <div id="gsv160" class="areaPop">
        The easy-starting, powerful, and quiet GSV160 commercial engine is designed for superior reliability.
    </div>
    <div id="throttlecontrol" class="areaPop">
        Full throttle control.
    </div>
    <div id="hrc216pdarearwheel" class="areaPop">
        Push Type Mower
    </div>
    <div id="gcv160" class="areaPop">
        Easy-starting, fuel efficient, and powerful, Honda's premium residential GCV160 engines are legendary for providing years of reliable service.
    </div>
    <div id="autochoke" class="areaPop">
        No engine choke required! Just start the mower and go!
    </div>
    <div id="3in1clipdirector" class="areaPop">
        Slide the Clip Director® to switch from mulching to bagging or discharge with just one touch. No need for a mulch plug or other attachments.
    </div>
    <div id="1.9bushelbag" class="areaPop">
        Our large capacity grass bags are balanced so they are easy to empty, saving you time and effort.
    </div>
    <div id="smartdrive" class="areaPop">
        Easily adjust the mower's speed to your stride by rotating the control. 5 position adjustable control for comfort. Variable speed from 0 to 4 mph.
    </div>
    <div id="electicstart" class="areaPop">
        Self charging electic start allows for simple, effortless key start.
    </div>
    <div id="sidedischarge" class="areaPop">
        Side discharge for easier raking or mulch depending on your preference.
    </div>
    <div id="1speedselfpropelled" class="areaPop">
        Single speed self propelled mower.
    </div>
    <div id="gcv190" class="areaPop">
        Easy-starting, fuel efficient, and powerful, Honda's premium residential GCV190 engines are legendary for providing years of reliable service.
    </div>
    <div id="selectdrive" class="areaPop">
        Easily adjust the mower's speed to your stride by rotating the speed adjust dial. Then engage the Select Drive control for intuitive, comfortable speed control. Variable speed from 0 to 4 mph.
    </div>
    <div id="versamow" class="areaPop">
        Honda's revolutionary Versamow System™ allows you to mulch, bag, discharge, and shred leaves - or even a combination of mulching and bagging! Just slide the convenient Clip Director® knob to choose how much grass is bagged or mulched. No tools or costly attachments are needed. It's the ultimate in convenience and versatility.
    </div>
    <div id="hrcdeck" class="areaPop">
        Heavy duty steel deck with a 21" cutting path. 8 height adjustments from 3/4" to 4". Bumpers protect the deck all the wat around.
    </div>
    <div id="hrrdeck" class="areaPop">
        Heavy duty steel deck with a 21" cutting path. 6 height adjustments from 1 1/8" to 4".
    </div>
    <div id="hrsdeck" class="areaPop">
        Heavy duty steel deck with a 21" cutting path. 6 height adjustments from 1" to 3 1/2".
    </div>
    <div id="hrxdeck" class="areaPop">
        This mower's 21" deck is made of NeXite®. This high impact resistant material does not dent, rust, or corrode over time. So durable it comes with a lifetime warranty!
    </div>
    <!--end of image map divs-->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
background-color: antiquewhite;

}

.subItem{
display:inline-block;
}

#bar1{
display:block;
border: 2px solid black;
background-color: orange;
width: 425px;
}

#bar2 {
display: block;
background-color: orange;
border: 2px solid black;
}

.center{
margin:0 auto;
}

.center2{
margin:0 auto;
width: 550px;
}


.mainBarItem{
display:inline-block;
}

.areaPop{ 
     display: none;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background-color: white;
     padding: 10px;
     width: 175px;
 }

.imagemap{
display: none;
}
```

The isolated image map that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style>
 .areaPop{ 
     display: none;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background-color: white;
     padding: 10px;
     width: 175px;
 }
</style>

<script src="../../jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/hrc/hrc216hxa.png" class="imagemap" alt="honda HRC216HXA" usemap="#hrc216hxa" />
<map name="hrc216hxa" id="hrc216hxa">
    <area alt="gxv" title="gxv160" href="#gxv160" shape="rect" coords="32,27,285,280" />
    <area alt="cut" title="microcut" href="#microcut" shape="rect" coords="326,45,560,280" />
    <area alt="speedcontrol" title="speedcontol" href="#precisionspeedcontrol" shape="rect" coords="326,280,559,512" />
    <area alt="rotostop" title="rotostop" href="#rotostop" shape="rect" coords="59,307,94,336" />
    <area alt="bag" title="bag" href="#2.5bushelbag" shape="rect" coords="115,476,150,507" />
    <area alt="shaftdrive" title="shaftdrive" href="#shaftdrive" shape="rect" coords="114,661,143,690" />
    <area alt="wheel" title="wheel" href="#9inchnexitewheel" shape="rect" coords="261,728,288,756" />
    <area alt="deck" title="bumper" href="#hrcdeck" shape="rect" coords="349,730,379,760" />
</map>
<br />

<div id="gxv160" class="areaPop">
    The GXV160 will make your dreams come true. Buy now!
</div>
<div id="microcut" class="areaPop">
    The Microcut will cut you. But if you don't buy it, WE will cut you. Choose wisely.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but your 2 script tags have different links, is main.js 404'ing on home.html? Or is there any other error in the console?

Comment: no errors. everything works perfectly when i open the home.html. except the image map that is

Comment: I'm getting area is undefined on area.bind('areaPop') in plunkr, any chance you could make a plunkr or jsfiddle showing the problem?

Comment: ill give jsfiddle a try

Comment: does this link to my jsfiddle work? i uploaded a couple images from postimage.org but not sure how to make them come up in the code http://jsfiddle.net/glazierpcrepair/Le25mv10/

Comment: Yes, it is still giving area is undefined. Did you define it in the isolated page but not home.html?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean but as far as i can tell from above the map is only in the isolated page currently. I wasn't sure where to put it or how to implement it into the Home.html or main.js to get the same functionality in home.html as I have in the isolated html file

Comment: So you are using "area.bind", area is a variable, but it is never defined in your code as posted. There should be an area = $('something'). If that event is never bound due to that error, then the code wouldn't work

Comment: oh i see what you mean. yea that little snippet is just for the popup to display at the mouse instead of the bottom of the screen. so i would put $("area) in front of that and it should go? since it would tell the hover function above it to so something other and the default of the bottom of the screen?